# консольная змейка на с++

Tags: c++

Решил по приколу написать некое подобие змейки на с++, но столкнулся с проблемой. Когда score доходит до 4, игра прекращается, подскажите пожалуйста, почему ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int w = 20;
int h = 20; 
bool gameOver;
int x, y, fructX, fructY, score;
enum eDir
{
    STOP,
    LEFT,
    RIGHT,
    DOWN,
    UP
};
eDir dir;
void Setup()
{
    gameOver = false;
    x = w / 2;
    y = h / 2;
    fructX = rand() % w; 
    fructY = rand() % h;
    dir = STOP;
}
void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < w + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < w ; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == w - 1)
            {
                cout << "#";
            }
            if (i == y && j == x )
            {
                cout << "T";
            }
            else if (j == fructX && i == fructY)
            {
                cout << "F";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < w + 1; i++)
    {
        cout << "#";
    }
    cout << "\nscore: " << score;
}
void Input()
{
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'a': 
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's': 
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void Logic()
{
    switch (dir)
    {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++; 
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }
    if (x == fructX && y == fructY )
    {
        score += 1;
        fructX = rand() % w;
        fructY = rand() % y;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Setup();
    while(!gameOver)
    {
        Draw();
        Sleep(100);
        Input();
        Logic();
    }
}
```

Comment: программа прекращается с какой-то ошибкой или просто закрывается? (посмотрите в консоль, может там что нибудь пишется)

Comment: Блин, еще и сидеть играть, чтоб дойти до 4? "Сама, сама, сама!" (с)

Answer (score 1):

А скажите-ка, вас не смутило, что фрукт все вверх и вверх ползет?

И слетаете вы не на `score == 4`, а на `y == 0`. Плохая погода — это не когда люди зонтики открывают, а когда дождь идет...

```
fructY = rand() % y;
```

И что тут будет вычислено, когда фрукт окажется съеденным совсем вверху?...

И ведь в `Setup()` написали нормально:

```
fructX = rand() % w; 
fructY = rand() % h;
```

Вобщем, целых пять выводов.

1. Учитесь использовать отладчик.
2. Будьте внимательны.
3. Учитесь использовать отладчик.
4. Copy-paste при внимательном использовании не всегда плохо :)
5. Учитесь использовать отладчик.